# PHP MySQLi - Return a single value from a query with bound parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is probably an extremely simple question, but i just cant find the answer anywhere!

I have a query that returns one row from my database.
I'm using mysqli to bind parameters and then execute it like so:

```
$sql_query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID FROM `Author` WHERE `Name` = ? LIMIT 1;");
$sql_query->bind_param('s', $author);
$sql_query->execute();
$sql_query->store_result();
$sql_query->bind_result($authorID);
```

I want to store the ID into a variable to use in another query but its not working. The only way ive got it to work is with a while loop like so:

```
while($sql_query->fetch()){
    echo "ID: $authorID";
}
```

But because there is only ever one row, i dont want to use a while loop. How can i use the result variable without the while loop?

Comment: `$sql_query->fetch_row()`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?
I cant see how that will help me :?

Comment: Just run that line of code...then do `echo $authorID`...no while loop required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to [`fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) the row from the table

```
$sql_query->bind_result($authorID);
$sql_query->fetch();
```

Now you are able to print your value

```
echo $authorID;
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work like you said, but you gave me enough to work with and i''ve figured it out. fetch_row() throws an error - apparently it doesnt like prepared statements for some reason. fetch() seems to work though :)

Comment: @user1636130 I'm glad i helped you out!